# right arrow equals right arrow

Tags: c, pointers, struct, double

I saw something in someones code that I don't understand. What does it say in the return statement?

```
static cell_ptr UD_self(cell_ptr c) { return c->U = c->D = c; }
```

here is defined:

```
struct cell_s;
typedef struct cell_s *cell_ptr;
struct cell_s {
    cell_ptr U, D, L, R;
    int n;
    union {
        cell_ptr c;
        int s;
    };
};
```

Comment: What language is this in?

Comment: That's ugly code, even if syntactically valid. It does two assignments and returns the assigned value (in this case `c`). Modern compilers are very good and would perfectly optimize `c->D = c; c->U = c; return c;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a shorthand way of writing this:

```
{
    c->D = c;
    c->U = c->D;
    return c->U;
}
```

The statement `return c->U = c->D = c;` works because the assignment operator `=` returns the value it has just assigned. This value is then used in the next assignment. It associates from right to left, so it means `return (c->U = (c->D = c));`